# Do images served over https get cached?

Tags: browser, browser-cache

It seems they are loaded again each time when I reload the page using Firebug Net panel.

**Update:**
I don't know if I can trust the net panel. It has an option to disable browser cache. It was selected. Does that mean it's the default? Is it only applied when the net panel is open? Will we ever know the truth about the SSL connections? Find out next time in, the case of the uncached webpage. 
[image]

Mac OSX 10.11, Firefox 43

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https

Comment: It looks like a legitimate duplicate. Thanks. The answer was yes. In modern browsers the default is to cache https content.

Comment: Sure they get cached, if you enable the browsers cache (option remains set, even is bar is closed) and add expires headers and etags at server side.